# How can I change the Netbeans VM options for java web application?

Tags: java, netbeans, wildfly, jmx

I have a java web application using wildfly 10 and netbeans 12. After that, I go to Services tab->Servers->Wildfly properties->Second tab (Platform)

Then I change the VM options to:

```
 '-Xms128m -Xmx512m -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman,org.jboss.logmanager -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -Xbootclasspath/p:/opt/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-2.0.4.Final.jar'
```

When I start Wildfly through Netbeans I see the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The LogManager was not properly installed (you must set the "java.util.logging.manager" system property to "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager")
    at org.jboss.logmanager.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.server.Main.main(Main.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    ....
```

On the other side, the Wildfly console shows as follows:

```
JBoss Bootstrap Environment
JBOSS_HOME: "C:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\wildfly-10.1.0.Final"
JAVA: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java"
JAVA_OPTS: "-Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms128m -Xmx512m -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman,org.jboss.logmanager -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -Xbootclasspath/p:/opt/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-2.0.4.Final.jar -server -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.management.http.port=9990 -Djboss.http.port=8080"
```

I see '-server -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.management.http.port=9990 -Djboss.http.port=8080' is added at the end of the line.

I wish to take out '-server -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.management.http.port=9990 -Djboss.http.port=8080'

How can I do that?

Comment: Is there a reason your adding the log manager to the boot class path? Usually the only reason that used to be needed was if you were using an agent that initialized logging early.

Comment: It's for testing the java web application using jmx. The idea is when I debug the java web application by Nebeans,. this starts Wildfly automatically. Then I do some test requests and after that I monitor it by Java Visual VM. Even though I detected the issue that Wildfly was not started by Netbeans because of the post explanation. It works if I start wildfly without Netbeans because I specify the VM options in standalone.conf.bat

Comment: It looks like your path in the `bootclasspath` might not be correct. Your `JBOSS_HOME` looks like a Windows path while the `bootclaspath` looks like a Linux path. That said I don't really see a reason why those `JAVA_OPTS` are required.

Comment: The tests are doing in Windows. I see Netbeans VM options are not used from netbeans/etc/netbeans.conf. I can't locate the path of the file that contains the VM options which is used by Netbeans.

Comment: I don't really know how it would work from NetBeans.